# Validation Rule Throwing error in test class

Tags: unit-test, error, validation-rule

here is my validation rule

```
    OR( 

NOT(REGEX(RIGHT(FirstName,LEN(FirstName)-1),"[\\p{L}\\s\\-.]*$")), 

NOT(REGEX(LEFT(FirstName,1),"[\\p{L}\\s.]*$")), 
(REGEX(LEFT(FirstName,1),"[\\p{L}\\s.]$")) 
)
```

I am Entering contact in test class

```
Contact con = new Contact();
con.firstname = 'Test';
con.lastname = 'Warner';
con.AccountId = acc.id;
insert con;
```

First Character is Capital and not special character allow. i'm following this validation but it throw error in test class is

> System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first
>   error: FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION, Special characters are not
>   allowed in contacts First Name / Last Name: []

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the test class.
The validation seems to fail even while creating a contact with no special character in the first name.

The condition NOT(REGEX(LEFT(FirstName,1),"[\p{L}\s.]$")))
and (REGEX(LEFT(FirstName,1),"[\p{L}\s.]$"))) are contradicting conditions.
One of them is going to be true.
I think the third condition for the OR should be removed:(REGEX(LEFT(FirstName,1),"[\p{L}\s.]$")))